# Margins are missing in PNGs generated from a PDF

Tags: flutter, dart-pdf

I'm using the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) library to generate PDFs in my flutter app. And I have to convert the PDF pages to images for a feature. When I try to do that using the [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package,  there are no margins on the page sides like in the PDF.

Like below:
[image: Screenshot of the pdf]
[image: The image generated by the package]

This is the code I use to convert the pages to PNGs:

```dart
var pageNo = 0;
await for (var page in Printing.raster(widget.pdf, dpi: 100)) {
  pageNo++;
  final image = await page.toPng();
  await File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Invoice-${widget.invoiceNo}-page$pageNo.png')
              .writeAsBytes(image);
}
```

This is the pageTheme I use to create the PDF:

```dart
pw.PageTheme(
      margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(40),
      theme: pw.ThemeData(defaultTextStyle: pw.TextStyle(font: font)),
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4.copyWith(
        marginRight: 40,
        marginLeft: 40,
        marginBottom: 40,
        marginTop: 40,
      ),
      buildBackground: (_) => pw.FullPage(
        ignoreMargins: false,
        child: pw.Container(color: PdfColors.white),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Try to Set `ignoreMargins: true,`

Comment: Check my below answer as well for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code Set  `ignoreMargins: true` read more about [FullPage](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/3.10.8/widgets/FullPage-class.html) and [ignoreMargins](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/3.10.8/widgets/FullPage/ignoreMargins.html)

```
buildBackground: (_) => pw.FullPage(
    ignoreMargins: true,
    child: pw.Container(color: PdfColors.white),
  ),
```